# Straight texture on curved mesh?

Tags: uv

I have some clothes here that i'm trying to texture. The stockings have a horizontally striped pattern. Trying to apply a striped pattern, it looks misaligned as the UVs are curved while the stripes are straight.

Is there a trick to this or does everyone just curve their textures and patterns to align with the UV?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this material setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]